# How do I search a model by specific fields in Rails with Sunspot/Solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

The gem and version I am using for sunspot is:

> sunspot_rails gem version 1.2.1
>   rails version 2.3.18

The query I am trying to search with and search method is something like this:

```
query_params = { :name => 'Joe Smith',
                 :email => 'joe.smith@email.com' }
```

How can I search a model with sunspot so that it searches via email or just name, since one can be blank for some searches (the below example did not work as expected)?

```
User.search do
   fulltext(query_params[:name], :fields => :name)
   fulltext(query_params[:email], :fields => :email)
end
```

*** I have reindexed the models and the fields are all searchable within the model as well ***

*** EDIT ***
The `user.rb` model is set up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   searchable do
      text :name
      text :email
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does any_of help?

```
User.search
  any_of do
    fulltext(query_params[:name], :fields => :name)
    fulltext(query_params[:email], :fields => :email)
  end
end
```

or

```
User.search do
  any_of do
    with(:name, query_params[:name])
    with(:email, query_params[:email])
  end
end
```

Try this due to it being a text field

```
User.search do
  any_of do
    keywords query_params[:name], :fields => [:name]
    keywords query_params[:email], :fields => [:email]
  end
end
```

Resource: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Fulltext-search

Comment: get the error: 
`Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for User with name 'Joe S'`

model will be updated on OP content. thank you!

Comment: I added a third option to try due to them being text fields.

Comment: thank you. tried that but getting `undefined method` for `keywords` and `fulltext` within the `any_of` block

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple way like below

On the model

```
searchable do
    text :name
    text :email
end
```

On the controller of action

```
@search = User.search do |searcher|
    name = [:email]
    email= [:email]

    searcher.any do
         fulltext params[:name], :fields => name
         fulltext params[:email], :fields => email
    end
end
@users = @search.results #=> carry this to view
```

reindex and for good results restart the server

Hope it helps

Comment: get the error: 
`Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for User with name 'Joe S'`

model will be updated on OP content. thank you!